# Substream Source(EntitySource) cannot be materialized more than once

Tags: scala, akka

I'am trying to implement file upload functionality in my application using Akka HTTP. I am using Akka version 2.5.32 and Scala version 2.11.12. I write a simple code with directive storeUploadedFile, like in documentation (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/file-upload-directives/storeUploadedFile.html):

```
def uploadFile: Route = (post & path("uploadFile")) {
  storeUploadedFile("uploadFile", getDestination) {
    (info, file) => complete(JsObject("path" -> JsString(file.getAbsolutePath)))
  }
}

private def getDestination(info: FileInfo): File = File.createTempFile(tmpDir, info.fileName)
```

But when i try to send a request to my application:

```
curl -F "uploadFile=@data.csv" -X POST localhost:8080/uploadFile
```

I'll get internal server error and exception:

```
ERROR [ActorSystemImpl] - Error during processing of request: 'Substream Source(EntitySource) cannot be materialized more than once'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Substream Source(EntitySource) cannot be materialized more than once
```

What should i do to upload file without this exception?